# Search string in a row using input box copy selected cells from that row and paste them on new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping to achieve the following steps in a single script:

Take user input via the Input box.
Search the Worksheet("Sheet3") for that text.
Copy 5 cells B7, D7, F7, G7, I7 
from that Searched Cell and paste 
then onto Worksheet("Sheet2") at cells B2, C2, D2, E2, F2

this is my Code.

```
    Dim rId As Range, celS As Range, celT As Range
Dim wS As Worksheet, wT As Worksheet
Dim sId As String

Set wS = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set wT = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set celT = wT.Range("B2")

    sId = InputBox("Enter ID")
    If Len(sId) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set rId = wS.Range("A2:BM2210") 'start of search area
    Set rId = wS.Range(rId, wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, rId.Column).End(xlUp)) 'rest of data

    Set celS = rId.Find(sId, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)

    If Not celS Is Nothing Then
        Set celS = Intersect(wS.Columns("A:B"), celS.EntireRow) 'extract name
        If Not IsEmpty(celT) Then 'find next empty cell in target sheet
            Set celT = wT.Cells(wT.Rows.Count, celT.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
        celT.Value = celS.Value
    End If
```

Comment: So, what is the issue here?

Comment: i able able to copy only one cell i want all 5 cells value

Comment: You have the row from `celS`, so use `cells` or `offset` from `celS`  so `celT.offset(0,1).Value = celS.offset(0,3).Value` for example, or `cells(celS.row,5).value`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav im new to this , i will be More happy if you plot it into my Example

Comment: Bet you would :o)  You only gave it less than 2 minutes. :o)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i can copy only one cell value, where as i want to copy almost 5 cells from the search resulted Row, and paste those value into Sheet2

Comment: Yes, and that is what I detailed in comment #3.`You have the row from celS`

Comment: What column are your IDs on?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav THanks Bro !